# Seeding table based on view during seeding

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have a bit of a tricky problem that I cannot really figure out how to solve.

I use std EF 6 (Code first) seeding in my migration scripts where I seed about 20 tables with static meta data for our system.

However, I also have a view that I would like the "contents" of to be seeded into a different table (to get around EF CF not allowing foreign keys to views and therefore no "real" associations)

So I would like to do the following:

1. Seed Table1 with data
2. Create view on top of this
3. Seed Table2 with data from view

My problem is that seeding is done in context and in a transaction. So my "Step 2" above will seed from an empty view since the data being seeded into Table1 is done in a seperate transaction.

Since I cannot access the view in EF Code first, I try to seed Table2 like this:

```
public static class MySeeder
{
    public static ClassificationType[] GetClassificationTypes(StorageContext context)
    {
        return
            context.Database.SqlQuery<ClassificationType>(
                "select * from vClassificationTreeXml WHERE Id=@p1",
                new SqlParameter("p1", 1))
                    .ToArray();
    }

}
```

The tooltip in VS on SqlQuery() tells me that the query fired off will happen "out of context", but if I use parameters like I do above, it will be "in context".

But still - nothing happens.

What am I missing here?

*(The view vClassificationTreeXml is a somewhat complex SQL view on an Xml-chunk in Sql Server with XPaths/XQuery and I would rather not implement this in c#)*

UPDATE:

I seed my tables the scaffolded way of doing this, i.e. in my configuration.cs file with the following code:

```
protected override void Seed(StorageContext context)
{
    context.MyTable1.AddOrUpdate(MyTable1SeederSeeder.MyTable1s);
    // ... 
    context.ClassificationTypes.AddOrUpdate(ClassificationSeeder.GetTypes(context));
}
```

So I pass the context to my function where I try to seed from the view.

Comment: You can have multiple `SaveChanges()` calls in your seed method when you wrap everything in a TransactionScope.

Comment: I updated the question with my seeding code.

But what you are really suggesting that I add everything in my Seed()-method in a transaction-scope and then add a context.SaveChanges() after each seeding step?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that. After seeding (+ saving) the tables you'll have the view available with FK values. It's not uncommon to use TS for such scenarios.